# JBoss + RestEasy - WELD-001318: Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between Managed Bean MultipartFormDataReader

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, resteasy, jboss-weld

After upgrading to JBoss 7.4.7-eap, One of my apps refuses to deploy because of this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.register(RegisterBuiltin.java:58)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:272)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:98)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:140)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:309)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1551)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1551)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1551)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1551)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1846)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1769)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.registerProviders(RegisterBuiltin.java:148)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.register(RegisterBuiltin.java:54)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001318: Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between: 
  - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataReader] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataReader] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.resolve(BeanManagerImpl.java:1158)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.resolve(ForwardingBeanManager.java:94)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.resolve(BeanManagerProxy.java:117)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiConstructorInjector.construct(CdiConstructorInjector.java:66)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2835)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.addMessageBodyReader(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1068)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1841)
    ... 32 more
```

My resteasy jars are imported as provided dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>3.15.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

And I can confirm there are no resteasy jar files in my EAR file.

Yet I keep getting this error.

I do see that there are two version of the JAR file in the modules folder:

- ./modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.4.7.CP/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider/main/resteasy-multipart-provider-3.15.4.Final-redhat-00001.jar
- ./modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider/main/resteasy-multipart-provider-3.15.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar

I'm guessing this is some usual thing that is result of the upgrade. But is this possibly why I have 2 beans when the JBoss app tries to look up the managed bean?

Comment: Is there a specific end point that is causing this? I'm trying to think of how it could be reproduced.

Comment: never mind.. was a missing "clean" in maven job on build servers and it caused a resteasy jar stuffed in one of the EAR files and it caused all this ruckus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a missing "clean" in maven job on build servers and it caused a resteasy jar stuffed in one of the EAR files lib directory.

This was the cause of the 2 different resteasy jars on the classpath.